# Request Header is getting as null in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am having two mapping methods in my controller. one is redirecting to other.
    Before redirecting I'm setting a header in response. But I getting the request header as null.
    These are my methods in controller. both are in same controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/testStart", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public String testStart(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
            String token = "126712810-1289291":

            response.addHeader("authToken", token);

            return "redirect:/test";
        }
@RequestMapping(value="/test", method={ RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
    public String getTestPage(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

        String token = request.getHeader("authToken");
        System.out.println(token);  //prints null
        model.addAttribute("Testtoken", token);
        System.out.println("Test page about to load ..");
        return "test";

}
```

I'm using postman client to test this api. It is hitting the url and redirecting to other url. but the header is null.
I don't know what's wrong. can any one help me to figure this out? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **Redirect** method web app tells browser to load the page which you want to redirect. So this makes new http request from browser, the original requests are not reachable at this moment.

So your problem can be solved with **Forward** method. Web app forwards all request data to another handler method internally

```
return "forward:/test";
```

Additionally , please change your

```
String token = request.getHeader("authToken");
```

with

```
String token = response.getHeader("authToken");
```

because you are adding your authToken to the response object.(from comments HttpServletResponse -> [getHeader(String name)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#getHeader(java.lang.String)) works since Servlet 3.0)

**EDIT :**

this code will be your complete solution `"/test"` method supports forwarded reuqest and also supports request from browser. 
(You want to get token info from request becuase you want to call /test method without forwarding, so it works in this way, but when forwarding you cant add header so you tried to add in response and get it from request but that doesnt work in that way so you need to resolve token according to dispatcher's type so check the code )

```
@RequestMapping(value="/testStart", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String testStart(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    String token = "126712810-1289291";

    request.setAttribute("authToken", token);

    return "forward:/test";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/test", method={ RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
public String getTestPage(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{   

    //-----------------
    //resolving token
    String token = null;
    DispatcherType type = request.getDispatcherType();

    if(type == DispatcherType.FORWARD)
    {
        token = (String) request.getAttribute("authToken");
    }
    else if(type == DispatcherType.REQUEST)
    {
        token = (String) request.getHeader("authToken");
    }
    //-----------------

    System.out.println(token);  //prints the value
    model.addAttribute("Testtoken", token);
    System.out.println("Test page about to load ..");
    return "test";
}
```

Comment: header still getting as null.

Comment: you are adding authToken to response object , and trying to get it from request object. you need to get authToken from response object OR add it to the request object

Comment: @sparrow btw you can use setAttribute / getAttribute  for this data forward issue, it would be better practice

Comment: @Bolzano setAttribute also gives null

Comment: @Poori  I didnt try set attribute(it should work) but response.getHeader("authToken") works -,- ...

edit : i tried, and request.set / getAttribute works too , probably you guys are missing something ?

Comment: @Bolzano getHeader method is undefined for HTTPSevletResponse

Comment: @Bolzano getHeader method is supported only from servlet 3.0..older version contains only setHeader method

Comment: @PrasannaKumar sorry there is no version provided, and according to his code i provided that answer because i just tried to find out why he was adding it to the response and trying to get it from request, i guess i kinda find it out. currently added another solution.

Comment: ok no problem with that but try to mention all details in the answer

Comment: Thanks You Bolzano

Answer (score 1):

Use **`RedirectAttributes`** to pass parameters with redirect URL:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test1", method=GET)
public String test(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
   redirectAttributes.addAttribute("authToken", "val");
   return "redirect:/test";
}
```

**or** if you can use `forward:/test` you can go with `request.setAttribute` and `request.getAttribute`

Still if you want to add in `header` then use `RestTemplate` and `HTTPHeaders` and get the `response String`